# form doesn`t send data through var_dump($_POST

Tags: html, laravel, forms, post

this is my registration form and I tried to var_dump($_POST) and the result is nothing it shows me this

```
array (size=0)
empty
```

I gave the attribute `name` to every input field

I'm really sure it's an very small thing that I dont think about this time.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('register')}}">
                    @csrf
                <h4 class="text-upper" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-right">Informații personale</h4>
                <div class="row cols-lg rows-md">
                    <div class="sm-col-6" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-right">
                        <div class="field-group">
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input class="field-control" id="name" name="first_name" placeholder="Nume" required="required" />
                                <span class="field-back"></span>
                                @if ($errors->has('first_name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sm-col-6" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-left">
                        <div class="field-group">
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input class="field-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Prenume" required="required" />
                                <span class="field-back"></span>
                                @if ($errors->has('last_name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sm-col-6" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-right">
                        <div class="field-group">
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input class="field-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" />
                                <span class="field-back"></span>
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sm-col-6" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-left">
                        <div class="field-group">
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input type="tel" class="field-control" name="phone" placeholder="Număr de telefon" required="required" />
                                <span class="field-back"></span>
                                @if ($errors->has('phone'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4 class="text-upper shift-lg" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-right">Adresa de facturare</h4>
                <div class="row cols-lg rows-md">
                    <div class="sm-col-6" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-right">

                        <div class="field-group">
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input type="text" class="field-control" name="address" placeholder="Adresă de facturare" required="required"/>
                                <span class="field-back"></span>
                                @if ($errors->has('address'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('address') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sm-col-6" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-left">
                        <div class="field-group">
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input id="oras" class="field-control" name="city" placeholder="Oraș" required="required" />
                                <span class="field-back"></span>
                                @if ($errors->has('city'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('city') }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field-group">
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input class="field-control" name="zip_code" placeholder="Cod poștal" required="required" />
                                <span class="field-back"></span>
                                @if ($errors->has('zip_code'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('zip_code') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4 class="text-upper shift-lg" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-right">Securizarea cont</h4>
                <div class="row cols-lg rows-md">
                    <div class="sm-col-6" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-right">
                        <div class="field-group">
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <input class="field-control" id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Parola" required="required" />
                                <span class="field-back"></span>
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sm-col-6" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-left">
                        <div class="field-group">
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                                <div class="dropdown-field">
                                    <select data-placeholder="Selecteaza Rol" class="chosen" id="multiselect" name="roles[]" multiple="" >
                                        @foreach($roles as $role)
                                            <option value="{{$role->id}}" >{{strtoupper($role->role_name)}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shift-lg offs-lg" data-inview-showup="showup-translate-right">
                    <div class="field-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input class="field-control" name="terms" type="checkbox" />
                                <span class="check-icon">
                                        <span class="check-block">
                                            <span class="check-pin"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                <span class="label">Am citit si acceptat <a href="{{url('termeni')}}" target="_blank">Termeni&Condiții</a>
                                    </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-inview-showup="showup-translate-right">
                    <button class="btn md-col-2 text-upper" type="submit" name="button">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
                <?php
                    var_dump($_POST)
                ?>
            </form>
```

I've tried to modify even the action like this

```
action="{{route('register')}}"
```

What can it be?

Also, this is my controller

```
use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $roles = Role::all();
        return view('auth.register', compact('roles'));
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'address' => ['required', 'string','max:512'],
            'phone' => ['required','regex:^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}$^'],
            'city' => ['required', 'string', 'max:45'],
            'zip_code' => ['required', 'string', 'max:10'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
        if ($user){
            Profile::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
                'address' => $data['address'],
                'phone' => $data['phone'],
                'city' => $data['city'],
                'zip_code' => $data['zip_code'],
            ]);
        }
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. it was a problem with the validation.
Here i used `'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],` password confirm validation and i had no field for validation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to var_dump your input, do it on the controller instead of print it on the blade template.

Check your route to which controller and method this form is submitted, and then you can print it by using `dd($request->toArray())`.

And make sure the method has the argument `Request $request` to make it able to receive your input.

Comment: i dont have any route made specially for this register form. i know that laravel automatically mades it. I added the controller to my question, where can i add the request?

Comment: can you check it please? @Refo